# Como criar uma relação entre 3 tabelas Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-eloquent

Possuo **3** ***tabelas*** que é necessário fazer join's para acessar as informações. Pelas relação do `Laravel` consigo criar relações simples, como `belongsTo`.

Estou tentando acessar a informação da primeira tabela com o id da terceira tabela. No caso, pelo id da tabela 'agenda_dias' quero buscar o nome do paciente.

```
pessoas
  -- id
  -- nome

pacientes
  -- id
  -- id_pessoa

agenda_dias
  -- id
  -- id_paciente
```

Na Model Pessoa criei a seguinte função:

```
public function agendaDiaPaciente() 
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
                    'Models\AgendaDia', 'App\Models\Paciente',
                    'pessoa',           'id_paciente',         'id'
    )
}
```

Model do Paciente:

```
    public function pessoa()
{
    // Cria vinculo com tabela de pessoas. Inverso de hasOne();
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Pessoa', 'id_pessoa');
}
```

Model da AgendaDia:

```
public function paciente() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Paciente', 'id_paciente');
}
```

Comment: 1 pessoa pode ser 1 paciente e um paciente por ter varias agendas dias ? essa é a relação? Coloque todos os modelos na sua pergunta?

Comment: Uma agenda_dias possui apenas 1 paciente

Comment: então são todos relacionamentos 1 para 1 ???

Comment: Isso mesmo, neste exemplo estão todos relacionados 1:1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só vou me preocupar com os relacionamentos, estão um pouco estranho, mas, pela descrição seria isso:

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Pessoas extends Model
{
    public function paciente()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Pacientes', 'id_pessoa', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Pacientes extends Model
{
    public function pessoa()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Pessoas', 'id_pessoa', 'id');
    }

    public function agendadias()
    {
       return $this->hasOne('App\Models\AgendaDias', 'id_paciente', 'id');
    }
}
```

---

```
namespace App\Models;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class AgendaDias extends Model
{
    public function paciente()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Pacientes', 'id_paciente', 'id');
    }
}
```

**Busca:**

```
$c = App\Models\AgendaDias::find(1)->paciente()->first()->pessoa()->first();

echo $c->nome;
```

Comment: Vaaaleu. Eu estava achando que não era necessário acessar todas essas relações quando definisse na Model Pessoa.

Comment: Tive que fazer a seguinte alteração para funcionar. AgendaDia::find(1)->paciente->pessoa->nome;

Comment: Tem uma diferença de desempenho isso que você fez, porque não usou do jeito que eu fiz?

Comment: Aparece o seguinte erro: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2443: Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::pessoa()

Comment: tem algum problema na suas relações Matheus!!! porque ele já não deu problema na paciente! deixa eu observar aqui.

Comment: @MatheusHahn eu editei é daquela forma a SQL é otimizada e o desempenho melhor... a outra funciona, mas, cai no desempenho...